# ByRef Argument Type Mismatch" Error VB6

Tags: vb6

I am new to VB6 and spread.My VB project is making using of spread .In forms wherever the spread initialization is done,VB 6 is throwing a compile error as "By Ref Argument Type Mismatch" Error" .Is it because of the spread issue? I am removing some functionality from a already existing vb project So is it because i might have commented out some functionality. Kindly.Kindly provide your valuable suggestion.Thanks in advance.I am running the application in windows 7

Answer (score 5):

The "ByRef Argument Type Mismatch" error occurs when you are passing a parameter to a function that is using `ByRef` (the default) and the data type does not match what is expected.

```
Private Sub MyMethod(ByRef Value As String)
  ...
End Sub

Private Sub OtherMethod()
  Dim Value As Integer
  MyMethod Value
End Sub
```

Note that Value is declared as `Integer` but the parameter is declared as `String`, and as such are a mismatched.

Either correct the data types to match (Which way depends on what they are and their use), change the parameter to `ByVal`, or do both (the best option unless you explicitly want to use `ByRef`).

If the calling code is not yours, then it's possible that the `By...` was ommited resulting in the VB6 default of `ByRef` even if it wasn't deliberate.