# VBA complie error when trying to pass range as argument

Tags: excel, function, vba

I am passing two range arguments in a function. One is working fine but second is giving compile error.

Here I am calling the function -

```
Set SourceRange = Sheets("QueryResult").Range("QueryResult")
Set DestinationRange = Sheets("TradeUnderlyingCptyWWRTemplate").Range("CounterpartyName")
Call PopulateDetails(23, SourceRange, DestinationRange, 2, 8)
```

And here is the function:

```
Function PopulateDetails(SourceColumns As Integer, Srce As Range, Destination As Range, DestinationColums As Integer, DestinationRows As Integer)

Dim CellName As String
Dim a, b, i As Integer

For b = 0 To DestinationRows - 1
    For a = 0 To DestinationColums - 1

        On Error GoTo Err:
        Sheets("TradeUnderlyingCptyWWRTemplate").Select
        Destination.Offset(b, a).Select
        CellName = Destination.Offset(b, a).Name.Name

        For i = 0 To SourceColumns - 1
            If (Destination.Offset(b, a).Name.Name = Srce.Offset(0, i).Value And Destination.Offset(b, a).Value = "") Then
                Destination.Offset(b, a).Value = Srce.Offset(1, i).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
Err:
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        CellName = ""
    Next
Next

End Function
```

However, it is giving compile error:

> byref argument type mismatch

with `SourceRange` highlighted in the code.

When I change the function to only have four arguments (deleting Source argument), it works fine.

Comment: I assume you have [`Dim SourceRange, DestinationRange As Range`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28238292/11683) somewhere, which makes it a Possible duplicate of [ByRef Argument Type Mismatch" Error VB6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25316331/11683).

Comment: yes, you are right, I have Dim SourceRange, DestinationRange as Range at the beginning of code. Removing that  line still produces same error.

Comment: Then click both links.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change

```
Dim SourceRange, DestinationRange As Range
```

To

```
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestinationRange As Range
```

Otherwise it is equivalent to

```
Dim SourceRange As Variant
Dim DestinationRange As Range
```

Comment: Bad bad Microsoft. How misleading.