# Ask for comment on passing array element to a function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code:

```
Function InputElmt(element As Double) As Variant
    InputElmt = element
End Function

Sub runInputElmt()
    Dim arr() As Variant, Firstelmt As Double
    arr = Array(1, 2)

    Debug.Print InputElmt(arr(0) * 1)   ' 1st call

    Firstelmt = arr(0)
    Debug.Print InputElmt(Firstelmt)    ' 2nd call

    Debug.Print InputElmt(arr(0))       ' 3rd call: error
End Sub
```

The sub calls the function `InputElmt` three times. The first two produce the correct results, while the last brings about an error (see [compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkx9u.png)).

My interpretation is that the third call passes a string of `arr(0)` to the function rather than its evaluation. In contrast, in the first two calls `arr(0)` are evaluated.

My questions are

1) is my explanation correct? and

2) is this error related to ByRef or ByVal as the error message might have indicated?

Comment: The third call does not pass a string, add a `Debug.Print TypeName(arr(0))`. So strictly speaking IMHO the answers to the first questions is No. The answer to the second question (which I do not really understand) is _The reason for this is that VBA passes in variables by reference by default which means that the data types have to match exactly between caller and callee._ See also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/byref-argument-type-mismatch).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ByRef Argument Type Mismatch" Error VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25316331/11683)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options

*First*

```
Function InputElmt(ByVal element As Double) As Variant
    InputElmt = element
End Function
```

*Second*

```
Debug.Print InputElmt((arr(0)))       ' 3rd call: no error with parentheses
```

Pay attention to the parentheses

> Placing the argument in its own set of parentheses forces evaluation
>   of it as an expression.

For further information have a look into the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/byref-argument-type-mismatch)

Answer (score 1):

Your second variable is `double`, but the third variable is variant. Your user-defined function requires a `double` variable, and in the procedure, applying a variant will result in a mismatch error.

Comment: `? typename(arr(0))` is integer; `arr(0)` is displayed as variant/integer. i am confused which one is its real type

Comment: @XianhaoZHU `TypeName` only makes sense when called on a `Variant`. It tells you which subtype is stored in the variant. The actual type is therefore `Variant/Integer`.

Comment: @XianhaoZHU, Because we defined the type as a Dim arr () As Variant in Sub runInputElmt (), the problem is that the variables called double and variant are inconsistent in the user-defined function InputElmt (element As Double)

Comment: @Dy.Lee I see. Basically, `arr` is an array with all elements being variant. `arr(0)' is fundamentally a variant storing an integer.